# Read from file and search in another file in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, file, spring-batch

In one of my Spring Batch processes I have a file for input. In the ItemProcessor for each record I have to search a value in a second file. What is the best solution to achieve this? Both files could have thousand of records and I wouldn't like to put the data of the second file in a "for" loop.

Thanks

Comment: I found a great  solution in Google Code: the algorithm is "External Sort". (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) and for download it, in this link http://code.google.com/p/externalsortinginjava/